# Can I replace a switch with values of 0,1,2 & 3 with some binary logic that will set values in four fields?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
        switch (buttonsValue)
        {
            case 0:
                vm.ABtnVisible = false;
                vm.BBtnVisible = false;
                vm.CBtnVisible = false;
                vm.DBtnVisible = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                vm.ABtnVisible = false;
                vm.BBtnVisible = false;
                vm.CBtnVisible = false;
                vm.DBtnVisible = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                vm.ABtnVisible = true;
                vm.BBtnVisible = false;
                vm.CBtnVisible = false;
                vm.DBtnVisible = true;
                break;
            case 3:
                vm.ABtnVisible = true;
                vm.BBtnVisible = true;
                vm.CBtnVisible = true;
                vm.DBtnVisible = true;
                break;
        }
```

Is there any way using binary logic that I could take the `buttonsValue` number and use that to set the appropriate values instead of using a `switch`?

Comment: I personally would use `vm.ABtnVisible = buttonsValue >= 2;` etc. Four lines of code, and easy to understand.

Comment: Do you need it to be 0..3? If yes, use @Dmitry's answer, otherwise you could use an `enum` with `[Flags]`

Comment: Can you explain what an enum with [Flags] is?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `buttonsValue` is in `[0..3]` range:

```
vm.ABtnVisible = buttonsValue >= 2;
vm.BBtnVisible = buttonsValue == 3;
vm.CBtnVisible = buttonsValue == 3;
vm.DBtnVisible = buttonsValue >= 1;
```